# why do they have a system string and standard string

Tags: c++, string

Why do they have a `System::String` and a `std::string` in c++?

I couldn't find anything about this, except some topics about converting the one to another.

I noticed this when I want to put information of a `textbox` into a `std::string` variable. so I had to do some odd converting to get this.

Why do they have these 2 different strings when they actually do the same for coding? (holding a string value).

Comment: `System::String` isn't C++ standard. It's a C++-CLI specific extension.

Comment: There is no `System::string` in C++. Perhaps you are thinking of C# or managed C++ from Microsoft.

Comment: I'm using it on Visual Studio 2015 so yes, it's probbably managed C++ from Microsoft. I'm using a GUI so it needs to communicate with a textbox that's probably why they have `System::String` in it (`std::string`, doesn't work with `textbox->Text`)

Comment: The whole point of namespaces is exactly so we can have multiple types with the same name. Microsoft could even have named it `System::string`  and there still wouldn't have been a name clash. `system::string` would have worked because that clashes with the old non-namespace `system()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` is a class template from the c++ standard library that stores and manipulates strings. The data in `std::string` is basically a sequence of bytes, i.e. it doesn't have en encoding. `std::string` supports the most basic set of operations that you would expect from a string, namely it gives you methods for substring search and replace.

`System::string` is a class from Microsoft's .Net framework. It represents text as a series of Unicode characters, and has some more specialized methods like `StartsWith`, `EndsWith`, `Split`, `Trim`, ans so on.